# Using Bash to execute commands

Tags: bash

So, basically I'm using a software called xspec.

```
 aakif@aakif-ubuntu:~$ xspec

    XSPEC version: 12.11.1
Build Date/Time: Tue Mar 30 13:44:35 2021
XSPEC12>
```

now Im using a this shell script to try to run a few commands ( named it *plot_script.sh* )

```
xspec 
data /media/aakif/TCIS/NuStar/nu60160836002AB01.pha
tcl ig bad
ig **-0.3 1.5-**
mo tbabs*po
give N_H value for tbabs
po index
freeze 1
fit 100
setplot ene
cpd /media/aakif/TCIS/NuStar/plot/0.3-1.5.gif /gif
plot ld res
cpd none
```

but it only runs the first command and i get:

```
XSPEC version: 12.11.1
Build Date/Time: Tue Mar 30 13:44:35 2021
XSPEC12>
```

But it only runs the whole thing once I've quitted

```
aakif@aakif-ubuntu:~$ bash plot_script.sh 

    XSPEC version: 12.11.1
Build Date/Time: Tue Mar 30 13:44:35 2021

XSPEC12>quit
Do you really want to exit? (y) y
XSPEC: quit
plot_script.sh: line 2: data: command not found
plot_script.sh: line 3: ig: command not found
plot_script.sh: line 4: ig: command not found
plot_script.sh: line 5: mo: command not found
plot_script.sh: line 6: give: command not found
plot_script.sh: line 7: po: command not found
plot_script.sh: line 8: freeze: command not found
plot_script.sh: line 9: fit: command not found
plot_script.sh: line 10: setplot: command not found
plot_script.sh: line 11: cpd: command not found
plot_script.sh: line 12: plot: command not found
plot_script.sh: line 13: cpd: command not found
```

now what i want to do is give these commands from line 2 onward sequentially in xspec.

Can someone suggest a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The first line `xspec` only starts the program in interactive mode, but the other commands are then executed in the shell.

To run the commands with xspec, you can do this, as written [here](https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/xanadu/xspec/manual/node24.html):

Create file `script`:

```
data /media/aakif/TCIS/NuStar/nu60160836002AB01.pha
tcl ig bad
ig **-0.3 1.5-**
mo tbabs*po
give N_H value for tbabs
po index
freeze 1
fit 100
setplot ene
cpd /media/aakif/TCIS/NuStar/plot/0.3-1.5.gif /gif
plot ld res
cpd none
exit
```

Then run `xspec - script &` in shell.

Comment: i tried this but it did not work out exactly a it should. it runs some commands more than 1 time and does not run some.